# How align(register) and merge point clouds to get full 3d model?

Tags: opencv, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, stereo-3d, ransac

I want to get 3d model of some real word object.
I have two web cams and using openCV and SBM for stereo correspondence I get point cloud of the scene, and filtering through z I can get point cloud only of object.
I know that ICP is good for this purprose, but it needs point clouds to be initally good aligned, so it is combined with SAC to achieve better results.
But my SAC fitness score it too big smth like 70 or 40, also ICP doesn't give good results.

My questions are:
Is it ok for ICP if I just rotate the object infront of cameras for obtaining point clouds? What angle of rotation must be to achieve good results? Or maybe there are better way of taking pictures of the object for getting 3d model?  Is it ok if my point clouds will have some holes? What is maximal acceptable fitness score of SAC for good ICP, and what is maximal fitness score of good ICP?

Example of my point cloud files: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1VdSoFbwNShcmo4ZUhPWjZHWG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you know by which angle you rotated your object between recordings, you can apply the reverse rotation to the corresponding pointcloud. That should give you give you a good enough starting point for ICP, so you wouldn't need SAC. For the angle of rotation between recordings: you'll have to figure that out by trial and error. You can start by rotating by 20 degrees, which should give plenty of overlap for ICP. Then you can try to increase the angle, so you don't have to scan as often.

Comment: @HenningJ: Ok, thanks but what if I don't know angle? I manually rotate by hand, and don't know the angle. And where should I set angle in ICP ?

Comment: You'd have to rotate the pointcloud before feeding it into the ICP. For the angle: you could just guess it. If you get it anywhere close to correct, that should be enough for the ICP. To verify that it works at all you could visualize both pointclouds together before applying ICP and maybe align them manually.

Comment: @HenningJ: I'll try what you say. But I want fully automatic point cloud alignment, without guesing angle is it possible? I don't want to do manual work.

Comment: Sure it's possible. I just like starting small and building on that. One of the PCL tutorials sounds pretty much like what you want to do: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/in_hand_scanner.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice and experience is that you already have rgb images or grey. ICP is an good application for optimising the point cloud, but has some troubles aligning them.

First start with rgb odometry (through feature points aligning the point cloud (rotated from each other)) then use and learn how ICP works with the already mentioned point cloud library. Let rgb features giving you a prediction and then use ICP to optimize that when possible.

When this application works think about good fitness score calculation. If that all works use the trunk version of ICP and optimize the parameter. After this all been done You have code that is not only fast, but also with the a low error of going wrong.

The following post is explain what went wrong.

> Using ICP, we refine this transformation using only geometric information. However, here ICP decreases the precision. What happens is that ICP tries to match as many corresponding points as it can. Here the background behind the screen has more points that the screen itself on the two scans. ICP will then align the clouds to maximize the correspondences on the background. The screen is then misaligned
>   https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/ICP

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried with little angle rotation, and ICP good result with fitnes score about 0.02-0.05, but when I align all these point clouds for getting model, I get very bad results. I try sac for initial gues, with different fueauture descriptors, but wasn't able to get good initial gues. And as I see most of pcl feature descriptors don't use color information. What you suggest me to do? And what's the easiest way gor getting object model aligning its point clouds

Comment: If you need I can share my exampe pcd databases

Comment: don't look to the fitnis score, try to use the trunk version of PCL: https://github.com/otherlab/pcl/blob/master/doc/tutorials/content/sources/registration_api/example1.cpp

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried these code but after first step my transformation Nan values.

Comment: there is a function for that that delete those, google search and there is the function name, don't forget normals are needed to be calculated

Comment: No, you don't understand, I have no Nan's in input clouds, the problem is, that the function that finds transformation matrix, return matrix with values: -1.#IND 1.#QNAN -1.#IND 0 -1.#IND -1.#IND 1.#QNAN 0 1.#QNAN -1.#IND -1.#IND 0 0 0 0 1

Comment: Then he couldn't find the solution, what is your data ?

Comment: I post example of my data in question